# Mac sending weird keystrokes in terminal

Tags: macos, vim, terminal

Quite often but not always I'd receive some strange keystrokes in my terminal(OS X El Capitan). It looks like a sequence of:

```
^[[O^[[I
^[[O^[[I^[[O^[[I^[[O^[[I^[[O^[[I^[[O^[[I^C
```

this is so annoying especially when I have vim open it seems to bring up identifier search and I have to hit Enter to continue each time. I can verify this  happens in iterm2 as well.

Did this ever happen to anyone else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are an artifact of the changes in *El Capitan* to support xterm-style mouse protocol.  The odd characters can tell a program when the mouse has moved in/out of the window (or clicked to gain/lose focus).

Some application you have run turns on this feature without handling it properly (or stopping it when the application ends).

Further reading:

- [FocusIn/FocusOut](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-FocusIn_FocusOut) (XTerm Control Sequences)
- [Mouse Tracking](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Mouse-Tracking) (XTerm Control Sequences)

Comment: wow thanks for saving my life. I did so much search but couldn't find any clue and your answer was tremendously helpful. Eventually I used a command suggested in http://superuser.com/questions/931873/o-and-i-appearing-on-iterm2-when-focus-lost/1017817 to resolve the issue whenever it happens.